# How to remove the white background in android alertdialoge

Tags: android

I am new to android..trying to create a form in alert dialog..but facing problem in removing the white background in android dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set other background `android:background="@drawable/bg"`.

`padding` attribute in your `drawable` file:

```
<padding
    android:bottom="-5dp"
    android:left="-5dp"
    android:right="-5dp"
    android:top="-5dp" />
```

Comment: i already set the bg image android:background="@drawable/create_form_popup_bg"..but still i can able to see the white space in the corner.

Comment: try to use `padding` attribute with negative value in your `drawable` file